# Can Firebase be implemented through a third party?

Tags: database, firebase

Simple question, is it possible to implement the Firebase database through a third party? I'm quite interested in trying it out, but the idea of making all of my code dependent on a single company's implementation of the database is a bit scary to me.

I believe I read that Firebase implements a NoSQL-like structure, so could it be implemented using Amazon's webservers? Better yet, is there a way to locally host the database?

Comment: Firebase is a hosted service, not software you can download and install yourself. That said: there are plenty of other NoSQL databases and data synchronization tools, that you can download and install. But Stack Overflow policy puts a recommendation out-of-scope.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose what I want to know is if I can use the Firebase APIs to interact with databases other than those of Firebase

Comment: I haven't seen any other back-end implement Firebase's APIs.

Comment: Considering that the data is stored as JSON, that you can import or export it at any time, what is so scary about using an awesome, lightning-fast, real-time product that is blazing the trail of how databases will work in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking if you can use the Firebase clients with server side software that runs on your own computers.

No, not easily anyway.

The real time features of Firebase are a combination of code in the client and server side. Theoretically you could reverse engineer the client libraries and write a wrapper for another server side database, but at that point you might as roll your own solution that meets your specific requirements, which would negate any time savings you'd gain.